# Not Able to get the values static fields

Tags: java, class, jakarta-ee, static

I created a Java Project Name A, there I have a class X with some static fields. This class implements singleton pattern.

Then I created simple web project W1, where I created one servlet S1. This servlet is initializing the static fields of class X (of project A).

Then I created another web project W2, and servlet S2. Now I am trying to access the object of Singleton class which is created and initialized by S1 (of W1). But I am not getting values of static fields which is assigned by S1.

I deployed all 3 projects in Same Server.

Is there any way to get the values?

Comment: Which application server do you use?

Answer (score 2):

Usually different web application are run in different classloaders (due to classloader isolation) on the application server, so in fact your're using 3 different classes (each loaded by different classloader) - not just one.